# How can I introduce a new generic parameter without declaring it?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a type union, and have one of those type unions extend an existing type:

```js
// The existing type
type Foo<V> = { value: V; onChange: (value: V) => void };

// A type union that uses Foo
type ADT = ({ kind: "foo" } & Foo<any>) | { kind: "bar" };

// Function that accepts it
function adt(adt: ADT) {}
```

However, the `Foo<any>` means that `V` = `any` and then the type of the `onChange`'s value is `any`:

```js
adt({ kind: "foo", value: 1, onChange: (value) => {
  // value is any
}});
```

I want to do something like:

```
type ADT = ({ kind: "foo" } & Foo<infer V> | { kind: "bar" };
```

But I can't use the `infer` syntax outside of an `extends` clause.

And I specifically don't want to declare `V` on `ADT` itself, i.e. `ADT<V>` because what `V` is (and even how many infers there are) depends on which type union is being used, for example:

```
type ADT = 
  | ({ kind: "foo" } & Foo<infer V>)
  | ({ kind: "bar" & Bar<infer A, infer B> });
```

Where each member of the type union as it's own different/inferred types.

Is something like this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use generics the whole way up to the function:

```
type Foo<V> = { value: V; onChange: (value: V) => void };
type ADT<V> = ({ kind: "foo" } & Foo<V>) | { kind: "bar" };
function adt<V>(adt: ADT<V>) {}

adt({ kind: "foo", value: 1, onChange: (value) => {
  // value is number
}});
```

The inference is done at the function call, so there needs to be a generic on the function.